# Hello! I want to redirect a category page from woocomerce to another page

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, categories

I want to redirect a certain category in woocomerce ,so when it is accesed(click on it) to direct user to a wordpress page that i chose,not on the default product page.My category is : /laptop-repair and i want when is clicked to acces the page
:laptop-reparatie/ which is a page created in wordpress. i hope you can help me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, take a few minute of your time to take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You will have much better chances of getting the answer you're looking for if you. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63980310/edit) your question with more details, informations, code, ...etc. Remember we're not next to you. For none-related code question visit Wordpress Stackexchange @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

function so_38101215_template_redirect()
{

```
if( function_exists( 'is_product_category' ) && is_product_category( 'category' ) )
```

{

```
    $redirect_page_id = 2022; // adjust to ID of page you are redirecting to  
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $redirect_page_id ) );  
    exit();  
}
```

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so_38101215_template_redirect' );

And i changed 'category' with the category name that i want to be redirected.
Its work.